# div responsiveness in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">

<div class="span4">
Image:<img  src="Tulips.jpg"  ></img>
</div>
<div class="span4 ">
<table class="table borderless">
<tr>
<td><b>Test image</b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>testing testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>120$</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Default button</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**My output1:**
[image]

and when i test for its responsiveness by using a mobile phone i get an **output2** as :
[image]

Can anybody help me with the code i have posted to make it look as output1 even for mobile view...thank you...

Comment: i am  using twitter-bootstrap...i dont need to write css....i just need to load the class i need to apply style...and i am new to this...so i have posted the code i have tried and asked what i need...

Comment: use boostap3 instead of bs2, the bs3 is mobile-first, and dont't need you bootsrap-responsive.css examples: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
<div class="row">
<table class="table borderless">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="span4">
Image:<img  src="Tulips.jpg"  ></img>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="span4 ">
<table class="table borderless">
<tr>
<td><b>Test image</b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>testing testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>120$</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Default button</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

thank you for you consideration..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">Image:
        <img class="img-responsive" src="Tulips.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
        <table class="table borderless">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Test image</b>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>testing testing</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>120$</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Default button</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```